# $l_p$ norm of principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that the sum of principal minors is equal to the $k$-symmetric function of the eigenvalues. Do we know a formula for the $l_p$ norm of the principal minors?

Comment: If there is no formula, is there any inequality between the $l_p$ norm of the $k$-symmetric sum of the eigenvalues and the $l_p$ norm of the principal minors?